# xna depth of field increase? i see backround color!

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

i created a scene in 3d max which is pretty huge, the thing is , this represents the galaxy and i will have a camera in there , but because its so big, the camera's view distance isnt covered by all the field , causing the background to be displayed at places, so how can i increase the view distance of my camera to view all the field? This is in XNA, visual studio.

Comment: You'll need to move the far plane further out or alternatively downscale your system with the modelview matrix. No idea how to do that in XNA. Note that this decreases the z-buffer accuracy which can create graphical artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aspectRatio = ((float)viewport.Width) / ((float)viewport.Height);
projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                            MathHelper.ToRadians(40.0f),
                            this._aspectRatio,
                            1.0f,
                            10000.0f); // Increase this number to increase the "depth"
```